# What is the gross weight limit for a Light Sport Aircraft?

Tags: faa-regulations, general-aviation

In the US, I see a lot of LSAs stating their take-off or gross weight limit as 1320lbs.  Can some of these planes have a higher physical limit and that 1320lbs is just more a category limit?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, 1320 pounds is the regulatory Gross Takeoff Weight for Light Sport aircraft.

From the [AOPA website](https://www.aopa.org/advocacy/advocacy-briefs/regulatory-brief-sport-pilot-light-sport-aircraft-final-rule):

> Light sport aircraft are defined as simple, low-performance, low-energy aircraft that are limited to-
>
> 1,320 pounds maximum takeoff weight for aircraft not intended for operation on water; or
>
> 1,430 pounds maximum takeoff weight for aircraft intended for operation on water.

Answer (score 0):

1320 pounds is the weight limit for land-based LSAs, or 1430 pounds for sea planes. The regulatory definition is in [14 CFR 1.1](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?rgn=div8&node=14:1.0.1.1.1.0.1.1):

> *Light-sport aircraft* means an aircraft, other than a helicopter or
>   powered-lift that, since its original certification, has continued to
>   meet the following:
>
> (1) A maximum takeoff weight of not more than—
>
> (i) 1,320 pounds (600 kilograms) for aircraft not intended for
>   operation on water; or
>
> (ii) 1,430 pounds (650 kilograms) for an aircraft intended for
>   operation on water.